# Does Realm use a cached instance when repeatedly instantiating Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Swift & SwiftUI app using Realm for data persistence. In my code, I am instantiating a new Realm instance each time I need to access the database, like this:

```
final class RealmDataManager {

  init() {}

  func getAccounts() -> Results<Account> {
    let realm = try! Realm() 
    return realm.objects(Account.self)
  }

  func addAccount(account: Account) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.add(account)
  }
```

According to the Realm documentation:

"Like any disk I/O operation, creating a Realm instance could sometimes fail if resources are constrained. In practice, this can only happen the first time a Realm instance is created on a given thread. Subsequent accesses to a Realm from the same thread will reuse a cached instance and will always succeed."

http://realm.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/swift/latest/

My question is - even though I am creating a new Realm instance each time, will Realm actually use a cached instance behind the scenes when accessing the database from the same thread?

Or does instantiating a new Realm() each time force it to create separate instances that are not cached?

I am trying to understand if my current approach affects performance from not reusing a cached Realm instance, or if Realm handles that caching automatically despite instantiating Realm separately in code.

Any clarification is appreciated!

---

[Added Later...]
The reason I came up with this question is I have to call RealmDataManager in the main and background threads in my app. So, I want to know

1. if creating a new Realm instance in a different thread will not use the cached Realm instance
2. if I need to hold a realm instance somewhere and need to access the instance in order not to fail to access the realm object.　（but my app can access RealmDataManager from both main and background threads, so holding a single Realm can cause threading issues...）

Answer (score 0):

(there were multiple questions so sorry for the long answer)

> even though I am creating a new Realm instance each time, will Realm
> actually use a cached instance behind the scenes

Yes! And your implementation is very common and practical. No downsides.

However, and probably just a typo, Realm can only be modified within a write transaction so for clarity it should be

```
func addAccount(account: Account) {
   let realm = try! Realm()
   try! realm.write {
      realm.add(account)
   }
}
```

> if I need to hold a realm instance somewhere

No. You do not need to do that in this use case. And your followup comment is correct. Don't try to access an object from different threads. From the docs

> To access the same Realm file from different threads, you must
> instantiate a realm instance on every thread that needs access. As
> long as you specify the same configuration, all realm instances will
> map to the same file on disk.

So what you're doing will work.

You may also find that making your Realm calls too specific can be a little confining - like in your case suppose to wanted to filter or sort the results first.

You *could* use generics (which I am not a fan of) or (what I suggest) make call to return the Realm and then make specific reads reads/writes within your functions. This also allows you to catch an issue in case instantiating Realm fails (which I have not seen happen) or if you want to expand this to a sync situation. Your RealmService is perfectly acceptable - we have a global function (and this is just a quick example, threading is not factored in)

```
func gGetRealm() -> Realm? {
    do {
        let manager = FileManager()
        let homeFolder = manager.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        let pathToThisFolder = homeFolder.appendingPathComponent("path top your realm file/Your Realm Project")
        let pathToThisRealmFile = pathToThisFolder.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")

        var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
        config.fileURL = pathToThisRealmFile
        let realm = try Realm.init(configuration: config)
        return realm

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error!")
        print("  " + error.localizedDescription + "  " + String(error.code) )
        return nil
    }
}
```

and throughout the app we just get Realm and do stuff with it

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
   var peopleResults: Results<Person>!
   .
   .
   .
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let realm = gGetRealm() {
           self.peopleResults = realm.objects(Person.self).sort...
        } else {
          //handle the fail gracefully
        }
    }
```

Threading:

Realm is sensitive to threading and Realm objects are NOT thread safe. There are methods to pass objects between threads (freezing them) and doing background reads and writes as well.

This is a very important read [Threading](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/threading/) and [`realm.writeAsync`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/threading/#std-label-ios-async-write) will initially be your friend. That being said, the biggest issue is trying to do a HUGE write on the main thread, tying up the UI so use the above to avoid that issue.

When you have some specific code you're having difficulty with re: threading, post a separate question including the code and issue and we'll take a look.